# Can Windows XP sp3 be installed on Intel 64-bit instruction set?

Tags: 64-bit, windows-xp

I would like to know whether Windows XP sp3 be installed on Intel 64-bit instruction set? I am referring to Intel® Atom™ processor D525 (1M Cache, 1.80 GHz).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the 64 bit version of XP, sp2 is as high as you can go.  If you have the 32 bit version of XP installed on 64 bit hardware, you can install sp3.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you install the 64 bit version of Windows XP in the first instance, Windows Update should install the correct updates (as long as they are available).

The [SP 2 download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=893fd6c0-6283-44c3-bb84-b2f0315b2ae6&displaylang=en) implies that there is a version of SP3 available to 64 bit users:

> To keep your Windows XP computer up-to-date download Service Pack 3 through Windows update now.

However, don't forget that SP3 is a roll up of all Windows Updates since SP2 and the SP3 release date, so you should have most (if not all) of them.

Comment: +1 for that! I always thought that they weren't going to release SP3 for XP 64bit.

Comment: None of the 64 bit versions are listed as being compatible with sp3